# Xamarin with Visual Studio Online

Tags: xamarin, azure-devops

I’m new to Xamarin, so I could be missing something obvious. However, I’m running into the following issue:

1. We are using Visual Studio Online as our source control system.
2. We create a new Team Project, use ‘Git’ and can ‘Check out’ and ‘Publish’ just fine.
3. However, the issue so far is with Components. We are using Xamarin.Auth 1.2.2 and when we push to the Visual Studio Repo, its only pushing the /lib folder. It’s not pushing the manifest.xml, samples, etc. So, when a different user pulls the repo, they are seeing errors about not being able to retrieve the manifest file (which makes sense, it’s not there). Even when they remove the component and go to the Component Store and re-add it, it still is only including the /lib directory.
4. We’ve confirmed that we can create a new solution and add the component fine. We created a repo on Github and it pushes the entire contents fine. It seems something is happening when we push it to Visual Studio Online.

My questions:

1. Has anyone been successfully using Visual Studio Online git repositories with Xamarin?
2. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

-Karl

Comment: Have you checked your .gitignore file?

Comment: It's the .gitignore file. VS adds a bunch of file types to it by default.

Answer (score 0):

I tested deleting the local Components folder now, and reopening the solution. Xamarin Components works almost like NuGet with restore on build enabled. Except installed Xamarin Components are listed directly in the .csproj file instead of in a packages.config file.

Using NuGet, you shouldn't add the packages folder with all the downloaded binaries to source control, only the packages.config file. So for Xamarin Components, you shouldn't add the Components folder with all the binaries. Since the installed packages are listed in the project file, there's nothing to add to source control related to Xamarin Components. Each client should be able to download the binaries automatically (or semi-automatically). Just have a look under the Components node in solution explorer to see if some components have errors and use "Edit components..." to fix any error.